# How to set label prefix application version with CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, thoughtworks-cruise

We're using [Cruise Control v1.8.5.](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/) We have next scenario:

- checkout source code from git repository
- run some scripts to build project (e.g. npm install && cordova clean, cordova build, also minify some css files, compile typescript ...)

Now we want to add label on successfull build. Therefore I found that cruisecontrol has labeller option, so I added:

```
<cb:define name="Mylabeller">
    <labeller type="defaultlabeller">
        <initialBuildLabel>1</initialBuildLabel>
        <labelFormat>0</labelFormat>
        <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
        <labelPrefixFile>X:\BuildFiles\myProject\version.txt</labelPrefixFile>
        <labelPrefixFileSearchPattern>\d\.\d\.\d\.</labelPrefixFileSearchPattern>
    </labeller>
</cb:define>
```

But the problem is that, this is done before source code is retrieved (git) from repository. I read version from my project and then CruiseControl with regex reads version and outputs something like: 1.0.3.buildNumber.

How to set/update label prefix version after retrieving source code from repository. It reads old one, before checkout. I also read about dynamic variables, can they be somehow set or something?

Appending project's xml:

```
<cb:scope ProjDirName="myProject">
        <project name="myProject" queue="Daily" queuePriority="30">
            <workingDirectory>D:\BuildFiles\$(ProjDirName)\Working</workingDirectory>
            <artifactDirectory>D:\BuildFiles\$(ProjDirName)\Artifacts</artifactDirectory>
           <cb:sourcecontrol module="Modul1"  TagOnSuccess="false" Branch="$(BranchDevelop)" />
            <tasks>         
              <cb:NpmInstall />
              <cb:Build />
            </tasks>
            <cb:Mylabeller />
            <cb:commonall />                
        </project>
    </cb:scope>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, embed the git hash in the label?

Comment: Well, application version is written in file config.xml. I wanted to read this value i.e. `<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1"` after cruisecontrol does checkout so correct version is shown by CCnet tray. I realized and tested that CruiseControl sets all variables e.g. CCNetLabel ... after build is started and before project's xml is read (checkout, tasks, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Figured that CruiseControl sets next build version when project build is started and before project's xml is read (checkout, tasks, ...).

CruiseControl project build log:

```
<parameters>
<parameter name="$CCNetArtifactDirectory" value="D:\BuildFiles\MyProject\Artifacts" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildCondition" value="ForceBuild" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildDate" value="2016-01-25" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildId" value="9d8234720e7342a3aa636aacc120eb13" />
<parameter name="$CCNetBuildTime" value="13:49:42" />
<parameter name="$CCNetFailureTasks" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
<parameter name="$CCNetFailureUsers" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
<parameter name="$CCNetIntegrationStatus" value="Unknown" />
<parameter name="$CCNetLabel" value="1.0.88" />
<parameter name="$CCNetLastIntegrationStatus" value="Failure" />
<parameter name="$CCNetListenerFile" value="D:\BuildFiles\MyProject\Artifacts\MyProject_ListenFile.xml" />
<parameter name="$CCNetModifyingUsers" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
<parameter name="$CCNetNumericLabel" value="88" />
<parameter name="$CCNetProject" value="MyProject" />
<parameter name="$CCNetProjectUrl" value="http://BUILDer/ccnet" />
<parameter name="$CCNetRequestSource" value="machineName1" />
<parameter name="$CCNetUser" value="user1" />
<parameter name="$CCNetWorkingDirectory" value="D:\BuildFiles\MyProject\Working" />
<parameter name="$LastChangeNumber" value="96ece86d55f83c8eb129cbfeb01724a3d37bb18a" />
```

Also I makes sense that Continuous Integration dictates application version e.g. major.minor.build instead that each commit dictates version.

Solution:

```
    <cb:scope ProjDirName="myProject">
        <project name="myProject" queue="Daily" queuePriority="30">
            <workingDirectory>D:\BuildFiles\$(ProjDirName)\Working</workingDirectory>
            <artifactDirectory>D:\BuildFiles\$(ProjDirName)\Artifacts</artifactDirectory>
            <cb:sourceControlMyProject Branch="develop"/>
            <cb:dailytrigger />
            <tasks>
              <cb:NpmInstall />
              <cb:BuildRelease />
              <cb:PublishAfter />
            </tasks>
            <publishers>
                <cb:commonpublish/>
            </publishers>

            <cb:MyLabeller LabelPrefix="1.0." /> <!-- version is fixed -->
            <cb:commonall />    

        </project>
    </cb:scope>
```

And labeller:

```
<cb:define name="MyLabeller">
    <labeller type="defaultlabeller">
    <initialBuildLabel>1</initialBuildLabel>
    <prefix>$(LabelPrefix)</prefix>
    <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
    <labelFormat>0</labelFormat>
  </labeller>
</cb:define>
```

Currently this setup is ok. In case we'll be developing version 1.1 upper setup must be changed. Main point was to get versioning working e.g. 1.0. + cruiseControl_next_build_number.